# Print a hash in HTML view with breaking lines - Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby, hash, view, ruby-on-rails-5

Im new to RoR! I have a instance variable that contains a hash in my controller:

```
def index
    @books = Book.group(:tittle, :author).count
  end
```

I shows on my index page as such:

```
{["first book", "Mary Lovelace"]=>1, ["second book", "Paul Smith"]=>3}
{["first book", "Mary Lovelace"]=>1, ["second book", "Paul Smith"]=>3}
```

This is my index view code:

```
tbody>
   <% @books.each do |book| %>
   <ul style="list-style-type: circle;">
      <tr>
         <li>
            <td><%= @books %></td>
         </li>
      </tr>
   </ul>
   <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The outcome I wanna accomplish is the following:
I want the view to print this instead
example

```
"first book", "Mary Lovelace" => 1
"second book", "Paul smith" => 3
```

Separated by a break line. Would like to hear your suggestions and solutions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<%= books %>` is not the answer here. That data structure is really odd as well.

Comment: Inside the loop, you should use the variable `book` not the collection `@books`

Comment: @tadman how can I improve it? Im all in for learning how to make things better!

Comment: @maxpleaner that worked! thanks! btw, if you dont mind. I have now a list with the most recent as the first, any idea how can I list by the ones that have the highest `count` ? for example
 "second book", "Paul smith" => 3 first in the list and then:
""first book", "Mary Lovelace" => 1" 
because the first one has the count of => 3

Comment: I'd honestly expect this to be turned inside out, as in: `{ 1 => { name: 'First book', author: 'Mary Lovelace' }, 3 => { name: 'Second book', author: 'Paul Smith' } }`

Comment: Also worth noting "title" not "tittle".

Answer (score 0):

max-pleaner answer in code

```
 <% @books.each do |book| %>
   <ul style="list-style-type: circle;">
     <tr>
       <li>
         <td><%= book %></td>
       </li>
     </tr>
   </ul>
 <% end %>
```